# remove/replace door hinge on wood door frame

Tags: doors, repainting

Can the screws be removed from the hinge and wood frame, the frame painted and the hinge reattached with the same screws and holes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the screws can be taken out and reused as long as you are careful and the holes and the heads of the screws are still in good shape.

If the holes are a little to large, the screws do not tighten down well,  you can jam a wooden toothpick or two into the holes and break them off flush, then install the screws for a tighter fit.